# Atomic read and delete in mongo

Tags: java, mongodb

I am fairly new to mongo, so what I'm trying to achieve here might not be possible. My research so far is inconclusive...

My scenario is the following: I have an application which may have multiple instances running. These instances are processing some data, and when that processing fails, they write the ID of the failed item in a mongo collection ("error").

From time to time I want to retry processing those items. So, at fixed intervals, the application reads all the IDs from the collection, after which it deletes all the records. Now, this is an obvious race condition. Two instances may read the very same data, which would double the work to be done. Some IDs may also be missed like this.

My question would be the following: is there any way I can read and delete those records, in a distributed-atomic way? I was thinking about locking the collection, but for this I found no support so far in the java driver's documentation. I also tried to look for a `findAndDrop()` like method, but no luck so far.

I am aware of techniques like leader election, which most probably would solve this problem, but I wanted to see if it can be done in an easier way.

Comment: Well there is [`.findAndModify()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) and variants. The intent is "singular", so you can basically read and modify or read and remove single documents at once. There is nothing that "reads" **and** "changes" in bulk though, since it's considered a bit of an oxymoron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I found no way to implement this with mongo.
However, since this is a heroku app, I stored the IDs in a Redis collection. [This](https://github.com/abelaska/jedis-lock) library I found implements a distributed Redis lock for Jedis, so this workaround solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **BlockingQueue** with **multiple producer-single consumer** approach, as you have multiple producer to produce ids and delete them with single consumer.

Comment: This is multiple processes, not multiple threads. Instances are running in their own JVMs. Or maybe I missed the point...